# Is it possible to target older iOS versions when using Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6 SDK?

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5, deprecated

IS to possible to use IOS 6 new methods and deploy on the IOS 5.
what approach should I follow?
PLease guide.

Answer (score 0):

Use weakly-linked classes to do this:

> Before using any symbol introduced in a version of iOS or OS X that is later than your deployment target, check whether the symbol is available. If the symbol is not available, provide an alternate code path.
>
> Suppose you set the base SDK in your Xcode project to iOS 4.0. This allows your code to use features in that version of the operating system when running in that version. Suppose also that you want your software to run in iOS 3.1, even though it cannot use the newer features in that version of the OS. Allow this by setting the deployment target to the earlier version of the operating system.
>
> In Objective-C, the `instancesRespondToSelector:` method tells you if a given method selector is available. For example, to use the `availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice:` method, first available in iOS 4.0, you could use code like the following:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController instancesRespondToSelector:
              @selector (availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice:)]) {
    // Method is available for use.
    // Your code can check if video capture is available and,
    // if it is, offer that option.
} else {
    // Method is not available.
    // Alternate code to use only still image capture.
}
```

> When your code runs in iOS 4.0 or later, it can call `availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice:` to determine if video capture is available on the device. When it runs in iOS 3.1, however, it must assume that only still image capture is available.
>
> If you were to build this code with various settings, you would see the following results:
>
> If you specify a base SDK setting of iphoneos3.1:
>   The build would fail because the `availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice:` method is not defined in that system version.
>
> If you specify a base SDK setting of iphoneos4.0, and then set the deployment target to:
>
> iphoneos4.0: The software would run only in iOS 4.0 or later and would fail to launch on earlier systems.
>
> iphoneos3.1: The software would run in iOS 4.0 and in iOS 3.1, but would fail to launch on earlier systems. When running in iOS 3.1, the software would use the alternate code to capture images.
>
> Check the availability of an Objective-C property by passing the getter method name (which is the same as the property name) to `instancesRespondToSelector:`.
>
> To determine if a weakly linked C function is available, use the fact that the linker sets the address of unavailable functions to NULL. Check a function’s address—and hence, its availability—by comparing the address to NULL or nil.

**References**

- [Using Weakly Linked Classes in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW3)
- [Xcode Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html)